# Creating a Lookup Object with Template Literal Types

Tags: typescript

I've got a type defined as:

```js
type Response = 'n_a' | 'n_o' | 'yes' | 'no'
```

I'd like to have a type that enforces that underscores are replaced with slashes:

```js
type ReplaceUnderscoreWithSlash<T extends string> = 
     T extends `${infer Head}_${infer Tail}` ? `${Head}/${Tail}` : T;
```

Everything works as expected here:

```js
type HumanReadableResponses = ReplaceUnderscoreWithSlash<Response>;
```

Now, I'd like to create a lookup object that I can use at runtime to convert from the underscore versions to the "human readable" versions but I'd like for the association to be typesafe.

I tried writing this as

```js
type LookupObject<T extends string> = Record<T, ReplaceUnderscoreWithSlash<T>>;
```

However, this doesn't provide key -> value type safety like I was hoping to achieve since this appears to be valid:

```js
const lookupObject: LookupObject<Response> = {
  n_a: 'n/a',
  n_o: 'n/a', // <---- I'd like it if this threw an error because the only valid value should be 'n/o'
  no: 'no',
  yes: 'yes',
};
```

Is what I'm trying to accomplish here possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to corelate each key with the `/` version of the key.  You can do this with a custom mapped type:

```
type LookupObject<T extends string> = {
  [P in T] : ReplaceUnderscoreWithSlash<P>
}

const lookupObject: LookupObject<Response> = {
  n_a: 'n/a',
  n_o: 'n/a', // error
  no: 'no',
  yes: 'yes',
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAbwL4CgYE8zDgJWAZ0gDt9sBeOAciIH0BDSuAHytokZcvQI9fZTSZseMABs6AY2ABVIgBNgUfBOjAA6gEsYACwDK4-NoA8AFTigYwefjj4YUDUQDmAPjgUUcL17MWrcmwADABIERwAzRTgACWA6OSQaUIiokzoNUSRAuAB+OBCEWPikAHpQtIysuAAuOBMAbgFBLDgAGQgIAGsAVzAAeQAjACtgCRhTcxBLa1t7R1d3RE84AG0ABThHOoBdGtxgMUkZeUVlVU0dfTpDIzWXFFQUFRJ4UQ6e-uHRmFr2rt7BiMxkY8IQICRgG4KAhlrQ6LVqCUGAAaWE0CAIohIyjIuAlEpwIwAWhJRLgAElKHI4KINJ1sFpNuE4DoNDYdFBgAB3OB0IjmKBQaBwAajOjdUgs7TYcGidBwABudFp1KVom62EMEG6ompotYJX4XiIGL4OOW3HwCMt5qQjSAA)

Comment: Beauty! Thank you

Comment: Elegant Answer.